# Accessing and scraping sporadically available Wikipedia sections

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I need to fetch some data but I'm completely stumped after trying a few things.

I want to access Airlines & Destinations from the [Albuquerque_International_Sunport's wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albuquerque_International_Sunport#Airlines_and_destinations) - keep in mind, I'll be going through a prepopulated list of airports with this data.

There are multiple "types" of Airlines: Passenger, Cargo, sometimes there's other (sub?)sections; other times there are none:

[image]

Articles for multiple airports will be accessed automatically - including some less known airports. This means I need to:

1. Check if "Airlines & Destinations" section exists
2. Take all data inside of any table
3. Scrape it; otherwise do nothing

I've tried using the ruby [wikipedia-client gem](https://github.com/kenpratt/wikipedia-client) however, the `.raw_data` method isn't even returning the section data:

[image]

Next, I went to Wikipedia's API: unless I am mistaken, but it doesn't return "section" names! This doesn't seem right but I wasn't able to get it working.

So I suppose that leaves Nokogiri. I can grab and parse the pages fine, but:

#### How would I go about detecting "Airlines & Destinations" section presence, getting all table data BEFORE end of section? I have a suspicion I need some tricky Xpath for this.

Seems to be the only viable solution.

Any thoughts welcome. Putting a bounty on this question when I can.

Edit: Perhaps it's better to simply somehow grab a list of all airlines in the world and hit them against HTML? Seems like it could be computationally expensive.

Comment: Perhaps use https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri or https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not an expert user of Nokogiri but maybe this can give you some idea.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albuquerque_International_Sunport"))

# this is the passenger table
page.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[2]/tr').each do |tr|
  p tr.text()
  puts "-"*50
end

# this is the cargo table
page.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[3]/tr').each do |tr|
  p tr.text()
  puts "-"*50
end
```

Comment: Thank you. How would I check if airlines & destinations (and by extension - these xpaths) even exist?

Comment: You can check if there is the related id, of course this works if the structure of the wiki page does not change. `page.xpath('//*[@id="Airlines_and_destinations"]').empty?`